# Send automated text when someone calls number

Tags: twilio, sms

I'm interested in sending an automated SMS message right after someone calls a number.

So, I already have an existing number that I'd like to use for this (I do not want to have to create a new one). The wireless carrier for this existing number is T-Mobile.

It seems that all paid services to do this (Twilio, Vonage)..will require me to get a new number from them. So, is it possible to use an existing number with these services?

Is it possible to do this for free without using a paid service? Maybe an API for the wireless carrier of the number or even some smartphone app.

What would anyone recommend here? Thanks!

Comment: Simple call redirect (forwarding) from carrier to a random .99 cent Twilio number? We do this with our 800 number. On AT&T this is *21 or *72, followed by *, the number to forward to, then #. Some phone number services have online dashboards to configure the call "action" as well. Otherwise you would have to Port the number into Twilio from your console which can take time, something like a number transfer. Otherwise, yes to use a service you have to sign up for it. Kinda not optional, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the kinda not optional haha. Ok, well good to know there may be an option to port the number. See, the problem with these paid services is that it's hard to even do a trial and see what they offer without a business account. You can't even talk to sales without it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**While you can in fact add a non-Twilio owned or controlled number you purchased elsewhere as a "Verified" number allowing it to perform a call action** to another number without changing the status or control of said number, where the end result is a person receiving a call from said number, **the same is not true of outbound SMS.**

From the Twilio [documentation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-Verified-Phone-Number-or-Caller-ID-with-Twilio) :

> An existing non-Twilio phone number, like the number to a wireless
> phone or a landline in your home or office, must be validated on your
> Twilio account before it can be used for specific Twilio account
> services.
>
> ```
> For free trial accounts you will only be able to make calls or send SMS from your free trial account to numbers that are verified caller IDs on the account. We allow verified phone numbers to be used as a caller ID on outbound calls for trial accounts as well.
> ```

> ```
> For upgraded accounts we allow verified phone numbers to be used as a caller ID on outbound calls (this feature not available for outbound messaging).
> ```

**However**, considering the flexibility of phone apps **you could in theory create (or perhaps download) an app that checks your Twilio account and an additional number purchased and automatically sends a text from the phone in question based on a detected action periodically simulating the desired effect**, which would require a constant physical device being powered to do so. In simple terms this is very odd and unheard of simply for being unnecessary.

Anecdote: We have a popular "vanity number" from another service. 1-800-POPULAR, for example. To send a text from this number as the receiving SMS number would not be possible. Nor would it need to be. Any user action performed would instead instantly be sent from the Twilio number, which for any end user would basically never be confused unless they were constantly being bombarded by random texts with the same message. Which again is unheard of.

Comment: So you're saying the better pattern to go with is...use calls my personal verified number...Twilio "intercepts" this and then sends outbound SMS from its own Twilio number? If so, that's what I'm used to seeing and it does seem to make more sense. Is Twilio the best to use for this kinda thing? So many services it's overwhelming. Will it be relatively cheap if I'm doing <10k of these a month? Ty

Comment: @user2402616 Apologies, the function I described is "outbound caller ID" ie. it appears a user receives a call or text (again text not being available) from the verified number. However if you enable it where a user calls your number and through it's native call forwarding (forwarded to a purchased Twilio number set up with a webhook to text the caller's number via the Twilio API) you can achieve the result, I believe you're asking. As far as costs and the subjective quality of "cheap" that can best be answered by yourself here: https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/us